# I got notification from FCM of google, but my messageBody was garbled. How to resolve it?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Post was successful, but the message body was garbled.

{"data":{"data_content":"測試","data_title":"Joyce"},"notification":{"body":"測試","title":"test"},"to":"myDeviceId"}

this.is my post code , is there any wrong? Thanks.

```
<pre><code>
public class HttpConnection {

    public void startConnection(final String apiUrl, final String jsonStr, final OnPostNotificationListener listener) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=Key");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    writer.writeBytes(jsonStr);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();
                    //Get Response
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append('\r');
                    }
                    listener.onSuccessful(response.toString());
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    listener.onFail(ex.toString());
                } finally {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }


    public interface OnPostNotificationListener{
        void onSuccessful(String result);
        void onFail(String exception);
    }

}

</code></pre>
```

Thank you for your help.[The picture of the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxl7t.jpg)

Comment: I guess this is related to the character encoding. Could you include in your question the code responsible to send the data?

Comment: I update my code now, Thank you for your help..

Comment: The problem comes from `writeBytes` method and representation of kanjis. Could you try to use `writeUTF` instead? I've tested it in a small Java program (`new DataOutputStream(System.out).writeUTF(jsonStr)`) and it looks like it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `writeBytes` method and the representation of kanjis (or other non ISO-8859-1 characters). You should use `writeUTF` method instead :

```
writer.writeUTF(jsonStr);
```

You can take a look at [this post explaning the difference between `writeBytes` and `writeUTF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996335/objectoutputstream-methods-writebytesstring-str-vs-writeutfstring-s). Basically, you should always use `writeUTF` when writing strings.